# Who is lord Janardana?? why is he called the prime cause of the material universe and param brahma? is there any scriptural proof for that?

Tags: scripture, vishnu, vaishnavism, vishnu-sahasranama, paramatma

in many places and even in some shaivaite puranas , he is called prabrahma and the cause of the trimurtis. but in internet or google there are a very less information about this. please provide me with proper scriptural proofs that he actually is the parambrahma.

Comment: Lord Janardana is Bhagwan Vishnu/ Krishna. As per Vaishnavite belief and the Puranas that consider him as their isht, he is the supreme Brahman.

Answer (score 1):

## Who is lord Janardana?? why is he called the prime cause of the material universe and param brahma?

Janardana means *one who gives happiness to people.* Janardana is one of the name of supereme God who manifest in the form of Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva. Even though Janardana is associated with Vishnu ([Vishnu Sahasranama name 126](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vishnu_Sahasran%C4%81ma)), it is the name of Supereme God or Param Brahma. It is also used for Lord Shiva in Shivasahasranma.

## is there any scriptural proof for that?

> Thus the one only god, Janárddana, takes the designation of Brahmá, Vishńu, and Śiva, accordingly as he creates, preserves, or destroys."
> [VISHNU PURANA](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp036.htm)